# How mathematical expression for relation between Gibbs free energy and equilibrium constant is derived?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$ΔG = ΔG°+ RT\ln K$$

I have searched it alot but couldn't find a clear explanation. Found a derivation on [Chemistry StackExchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/derivation-of-relationship-between-equilibrium-constant-and-gibbs-free-energy-ch)  Here I am not able to understand why we are taking Integral of VdP. Can someone please explain this step in bit more detail.

$$dG=-SdT+VdP\\
V=(\dfrac {\partial G}{\partial P})_T\\
\bar G(T,P_2)=\bar G(T,P_1)+\int_{P_1}^{P_2}\bar V dp$$

Here $\bar x$ represents molar $x$, i.e. $x$ per mole
$$\bar V=\frac {RT}{P}\\
\bar G(T,P_2)=\bar G(T,P_1)+RT \ln\frac {P_2}{P_1}$$

Defining standard state as $P=1~\text{bar}$ and $\bar G=\mu$
$$\mu(T,P)=\mu^o (T)+RT\ln \frac{P}{P_o}$$

Consider the general gaseous reaction $aA+bB\rightarrow cC+dD$
$$\Delta G=(c\mu_C+d\mu_D-a\mu_A-b\mu_B)$$

For "unit progress" in reaction. Using $\mu_i=\mu^o_i+RT\ln \frac{P_i}{1bar}$
$$\Delta G=(c\mu^o_C+d\mu^o_D-a\mu^o_A-b\mu^o_B)+RT\ln \frac{P_C^cP_D^d}{P_A^aP_B^b}\\
\Delta G=\Delta G^o+RT\ln Q $$

Comment: You should post this in [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions) because the physical relations needed for deriving this equation don't belong to the Mathematical domain.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri But it involves calculus

Comment: Deriving any physical relation involves the use of mathematical tools, but it doesn't mean that derivation is relevant to mathematics or can be explained by mathematicians. We could help out with doubts of mathematical nature if you wrote the derivation here, but Chemistry SE is still the better place to ask.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You're integrating $dP$ because $T$ is fixed (an isothermal process), and so the $dT$ term drops out. (Remember also that the notation $\left(\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial P}\right)_T$ reminds you that $T$ is held fixed.)